# Print Second Page Of PDF Using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am able to print PDF using VB.Net on Button click Event. But what i want is to print only Second page of my PDF.
Please help How can i do this.

```html
   Dim MyProcess As New Process
            MyProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
            MyProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "print"
            MyProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "D:\765.pdf"
            MyProcess.Start()
            MyProcess.WaitForExit(10000)
            MyProcess.CloseMainWindow()
            MyProcess.Close()
```

Comment: The code you have there is equivalent to right-clicking a PDF in Windows Explorer and selecting the Print option.  Would there be any way to select a page in that case?  No, there would not.  There is no way to do it in code either.  If a user wanted to print a specific page then they'd have to open it in an application that understands the PDF format and can send a specific page to the printer.  You would need to do the same, i.e. incorporate PDF reading capability into your app.  You could do that with iTextSharp or the like.

Comment: Can u share the link or can you show me how can i do this

Comment: Google not working where you are?

Comment: As commented above, this is off-topic (= you are plainly asking us for writing a whole code for you). But I want to highlight another issue which perhaps you haven't realised about: VB.NET is a compiled language (which comes in various different flavours; that is: you need to know more than just VB.NET to compile some things); not sure if there is (or will be) any site allowing to dynamically compile certain VB.NET code types (mainly now with the API-based Roslyn). One thing I know for sure: the standard functionality "run code snippet" which you included doesn't work, don't you see it?

Comment: What i Did is extracted Number of Pages to print from the existing PDF and Created new PDF with it; Then I Print the New PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Below Is the Function I have used to Extract Number of Pages required to print from the existing PDF

```html
 Private Shared Sub ExtractPages(inputFile As String, outputFile As String, start As Integer, [end] As Integer)
        ' get input document
        Dim inputPdf As New PdfReader(inputFile)

        ' retrieve the total number of pages
        Dim pageCount As Integer = inputPdf.NumberOfPages

        If [end] < start OrElse [end] > pageCount Then
            [end] = pageCount
        End If

        ' load the input document
        Dim inputDoc As New Document(inputPdf.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1))

        ' create the filestream
        Using fs As New FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create)
            ' create the output writer 
            Dim outputWriter As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(inputDoc, fs)
            inputDoc.Open()
            Dim cb1 As PdfContentByte = outputWriter.DirectContent

            ' copy pages from input to output document
            For i As Integer = start To [end]
                inputDoc.SetPageSize(inputPdf.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i))
                inputDoc.NewPage()

                Dim page As PdfImportedPage = outputWriter.GetImportedPage(inputPdf, i)
                Dim rotation As Integer = inputPdf.GetPageRotation(i)

                If rotation = 90 OrElse rotation = 270 Then
                    cb1.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, _
                     inputPdf.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height)
                Else
                    cb1.AddTemplate(page, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F, 0, _
                     0)
                End If
            Next

            inputDoc.Close()
        End Using
```